# avoid spaces between img

Tags: html, css

How to avoid the spaces between `img` tags?

The content in the print screen is marked

[image]

code:

```
#menu > img {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

<div id="menu">
    <img src="/gfx/menu.home.png" />
    <img src="/gfx/menu.functions.png" />
    <img src="/gfx/menu.prices.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: How about remove padding and margins?

Comment: what do you mean? have updated my question

Comment: can you put it in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: remove the whitespaces, as noted in several answers, or float the images.

Comment: See here: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: If you read more at SO, you'll find 18 other workarounds. Let's have the 19th: use a single image + image map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float them:

```
#menu {
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu > img {
    float: left;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bzWYX/

Btw I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Comment: @clarkk Floating should work. Images that are siblings and floated to the same side should be pressed together (unless they have margins or borders). I would love to see a demo of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Remove spaces between the `img` tags in your code.

```
<div id="menu">
    <img src="/gfx/menu.home.png" /><img src="/gfx/menu.functions.png" /><img src="/gfx/menu.prices.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Such an awful workaround. HTML should ignore whitespace, I don't understand why this isn't always the case.

Comment: @bricker When parsing the HTML source code, if the browser encounters a sequence of white-space characters, it will condense that sequence into a single space. However, if there is at least one single white-space character between two `<img>` tags, the browser will create a Text node between those two image element nodes in the DOM.

Comment: White-spaces ARE ignored but not the last one. If you have multiple white-spaces together, all of them are ignore but the last one (by default). In my opinion, CRLF should be ignore by default also.

Comment: Someone else suggested setting `font-size` to `0`, basically removing the created text node.  I think it's ugly too, but in most situations inserting the space is actually the wanted behaviour - like two `a` tags next to each other, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <img src="/gfx/menu.home.png" /><img src="/gfx/menu.functions.png" /><img src="/gfx/menu.prices.png" />
</div>
```

Put the img tags on one line will do the trick.